# A question about coordinate adjectives

Tags: adjectives

I have seen that coordinate adjectives work independently from each other, belong to the same category, and can be separated with commas or the conjunction "and" and still sound normal even if their order is changed.

*A beautiful, silent car.

A silent, beautiful car.*
(Both beautiful and silent are matters of opinion)

On the other hand, cumulative adjectives have to build upon each other and belong to different categories, such as size (big, small, large) and material (metallic, gold, plastic).

*A large metal tube.*

However, I can think of some sentences where you have two adjectives that belong to different categories and still sound fine like coordinate adjectives. For example:

*She had a frail, small body.

She had a small, frail body.*
(Frail is a matter of opinion, while small is a matter of size)

What gives? Is it possible that some adjectives can belong to different categories and still be used in a sentence like coordinate adjectives?

Comment: _A frail, small body_ doesn't sound natural to me as a native speaker.

Comment: Well, that makes it even worse @KateBunting, because if you were to use them as cumulative adjectives you would have to place frail first (opinion comes before size), and the sentence would be "She had a frail small body". Even if you treat them as cumulative adjectives in the other way ("She had a small frail body") it still sounds worse than if you use them as coordinate adjectives, don't you think?

Comment: Native speakers choose the order of adjectives instinctively, not according to some theoretical rule. To me, _a small, frail body_ sounds perfectly fine. (I had to look up the 'correct' order for adjectives. [This site](https://learningenglish.voanews.com/a/what-is-the-word-order-of-adjectives-/4775294.html) recommends _Two tasty large pizzas_, but I would say _Two large, tasty pizzas_.)

Comment: Thanks for you answer, and I understand that is how people naturally speak. However, if you look up the rule for coordinate adjectives it says that if you can separate them using a comma like you did there ("She had a small, frail body"), you should be able to revert their order ("She had a frail, small body").

Well, perhaps that is one of those situations where the rules don't help much at all.

Comment: I agree with Kate here, it's instinctual (previously internalized from hearing or listening). In any case, the most natural sounding is: small, frail body. Who says *frail is an opinion*??

Comment: Apropos the order of adjectives, and not an answer: Example of adjectival order before nouns: "Opinion, size, age, shape, color, origin, material, purpose: A lovely, little, old, rectangular, green, French, silver, whittling KNIFE." I don't know if this helps, but I found the ordering of the adjectives kind of interesting! Don

Comment: Over on WordWizard, Phil White once contributed an article showing how inaccurate the 'Royal Order of Adjectives' rule is, proving that it is at best a general guideline. He gave an alternative breakdown according to type of adjective, but it either became very fiddly or remained riddled with exceptions. Just regard the Royal Order as a helpful guide, with idiosyncratic exceptions. But using no more than say 3 adjectives together is probably a more easily observed rule.

Comment: No; there is misunderstanding in the question. The bottom line is that cumulative adjectives are where the earlier adjective modifies the next adjective rather than the noun. (1) _A dark green jersey_ is a jersey that is _dark green_. The adjectives are cumulative, _dark_ modifying _green_ and then the two-word string modifying the noun. Compare compound adjectives. _A blue-green jersey_. Whereas (2) _a new green jersey_ is a jersey that is green in colour _and_ newly bought. (2) shows coordinate adjectives, each modifying the noun.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies. @EdwinAshworth, I checked the definition of coordinate and cumulative adjectives, and I saw that this idea of 'names that modifiy each other in order' don't always seem to apply very well. The example I saw was "little green bag", where technically there's no reason you couldn't say "green little bag", but it is unusual. Everywhere I looked it was stated that coordinate adjectives are separated either by commas or by "and", and if you write "new green jersey" you are actually giving an example of cumulative adjectives (age/condition comes before color).

Comment: Yes, there isn't a consensus on the definition of the terms. CGEL and ACGEL seem not to use them (almost certainly to avoid simplistic, inaccurate treatments of adjective ordering). Nordquist uses the 'modifying what?' test, which is usually fool-proof, whereas the other criteria sometimes have inadequacies (people disagreeing on acceptability of orderings, etc). // Bonnie Mills, at [Grammar Girl](https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/commas-with-adjectives), endorses the primacy of the  'modifying what?' requirement.

Comment: @RicardoMaia Punctuation distinguishes coordination from the stacking of modifiers. For example, _a powerful, fuel-injected engine_ is one that is both powerful and has fuel-injection"(coordination).  By contrast, in _a powerful fuel-injected engine_, "engine" is first modified by _fuel-injected_ to form the nominal _fuel-injected engine_ and this is in turn modified by _powerful_ giving the meaning "engine that is powerful by the standards applicable to fuel-injected ones" (stacking).

Comment: Revisiting this, I feel I ought to emphasise that @Kate's comment about what sounds right is important here. Just as one wouldn't coordinate two disparate main clauses for _a reason that isn't grammatical_ (eg 'John caught a rainbow trout for their tea and the nearby volcano erupted'), one often wouldn't close-couple adjectives that are semantic poles apart.  I'd want 'A beautiful car that's also silent,' say, unless preceding context licensed.